# Hbase integration test on Windows

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hbase

I have a new java EE application with hbase database.
I want to create integration test, and I use the HBaseTestingUtility class (startMiniCluster).

I work on Windows (Eclipse) and I get this error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.setWriteChecksum
```

My pom.xml :

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <hadoop.version>1.2.1</hadoop.version>
    <hadoop.common.version>2.5.1</hadoop.common.version>
    <hbase.version>1.0.0</hbase.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 

    <!-- Hadoop dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>     
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-test</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.common.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hadoop-annotations</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.common.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HBase dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-testing-util</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hbase-annotations</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I checked hadoop-core jar (1.2.1), and setWriteChecksum doesn't exist. 
Can you help me ? Thank you.

Edit : 
With the dependencies update :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:712)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
2015-04-01 09:17:56,834 WARN  [RecoverableZooKeeper :: retryOrThrow] Possibly transient ZooKeeper, quorum=127.0.0.1:2181, exception=org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase-unsecure/hbaseid
2015-04-01 09:17:56,835 INFO  [RetryCounter :: sleepUntilNextRetry] Sleeping 1000ms before retry #0...
2015-04-01 09:17:57,817 INFO  [ClientCnxn$SendThread :: logStartConnect] Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-04-01 09:17:58,818 WARN  [ClientCnxn$SendThread :: run] Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

The problem is I don't know if HBaseTestingUtility() works on Windows...
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong version of Hadoop for hadoop-core. See the HBase Project [HBase Book](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#basic.prerequisites), scroll down to a bit to `Section 4.1 - Hadoop`, where you will find a compatibility matrix. If you're using HBase 1.0.0, I'd recommend going with Hadoop 2.5.1 like you did at the top of your POM. Hadoop now uses `test-jar` types with their dependencies, so I had to do a bit of digging myself.

Your properties would look like this:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <hadoop.version>2.5.1</hadoop.version>
    <hbase.version>1.0.0</hbase.version>
</properties>
```

Your dependencies would look like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-hadoop-compat</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-hadoop2-compat</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hadoop-annotations</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>`
```

Comment: Ok, I agree. With this, I obtain : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information... The full stack is in my message.

Comment: Try turning off Windows Firewall, perhaps? Usually you get a Java popup to allow it through but I always turn it off to avoid any possible changes of a bad configuration.

Comment: Now, i have this error : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

Comment: It looks like the parts of Hadoop HBase depends on require the Hadoop Native Libraries to be run on Windows. You can follow [this guide](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BweVwq32koypYm1QWHNvRTZWTm8/view) to compile Hadoop on Windows; then you'll probably have use those jars instead of the Maven artifacts - since the Maven artifacts for Hadoop don't include the native libraries.